# ColumnTransformer creating estimator twice (and overrides default parameter)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Let's say I have the following DataFrame (*oversimplified*, of course):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
   'Hello', 'Bye', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Bye', 'Hello', 'Bye', 'Hello'
], columns=['A'])
```

I also have the following estimator/transformer, to cluster all the values of `A` into **N** clusters based on similarity:

```py
class Clusterer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, nclusters=2):
        print('__init__({}) called'.format(nclusters))
        self._vectorizer = CountVectorizer(strip_accents='unicode', stop_words='english')
        self._nclusters = nclusters
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # Vectorize all values, then cluster
        self._clusters = [
             KMeans(n_clusters=self._nclusters)
             .fit(self._vectorizer.fit_transform(x))
             for x in X.values.T
        ]
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        # Return cluster labels
        return np.array([c.labels_ for c in self._clusters])
```

Notice the `print` statement under `__init__`

I'm hoping to get the following transformation

```
A
--
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
```

Notice that everything has been encoded in either `0` or `1` (The example I'm providing is a really simplified version of the real data)

I've created the following transformation:

```py
ctf = ColumnTransformer([
    ('a', Clusterer(nclusters=2), ['A'])
])
```

However, after executing:

```py
ctf.fit_transform(df)
```

I get the following printed statements:

```
__init__(2)
__init__(None)
```

This is causing errors during the actual clustering because `n_clusters` is not provided.

Any idea of what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

So, this took me a while to figure out, but `ColumnTransformer` will actually [**clone** your provided transformers](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py#L450), when you call `fit` or `fit_transform`.

The way, **scikit.base.clone** works is that it gets the estimator's parameters through `get_params`, and then calls `set_params` on the new instance with the same values.

`BaseEstimator` already provides default implementations for `get_params` and `set_params`, but [they **assume** that you'll have attributes with the same name as the parameter](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L187), which is not true in my case (`self._nclusters = nclusters` due to the underscore).

After fixing that, everything works as expected.